# Angular: Http Post call to send pdf document to server

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular, ngrx

I am subscribing to a service `HTTP get` call hitting which i am downloading a pdf document.

How can i use that document, saving in any variable and trigger `HTTP POST` call so that i can send that document to server on any specific Action ?

Another doubt - How to get that document/document response and store it any variable ? After hitting that `HTTP GET` call simply file is getting downloaded. How to access that document in code ?

Server Language: Java

FrontEnd: Angular

Answer (score 1):

Convert your pdf file into BSON(Binary JSON)/ base64 type,
Simply store that converted data in string variable,
And pass that data into body of your HTTP POST.

Comment: This is not a good way to upload a large PDF. It takes time to convert to BSON and Sometimes API might timeout due to traffic.

Comment: can you please let me know how to do this ? I am unable to get document response OR document data. Just hitting that get Call file is getting download.

Comment: did you try with   responseType: 'blob' ? you can pass it to get call as second parameter . http.get(url, {  responseType: 'blob',
     })
.